# Adding and building a document from gRPC request in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, grpc, grpc-java

Currently transitioning an application from REST to gRPC based, how would you add a document into mongodb collection using gRPC request parameters.

```
@Override
public void insert(UserOuter.Request request, StreamObserver<UserOuter.Response> responseObserver) {
    System.out.println(request.getName());
    System.out.println(request.getEmail());

    // json based approach
    /*Document document = Document.parse(user); 
    database.getCollection("user")
            .insertOne(document);*/
}
```

Attempt

```
Document document = Document.parse(request.toString());
    database.getCollection("user")
            .insertOne(document);
```

What I can think is to build a JSON string using the request parameters but wondering if there's a better way?

Comment: request.toString doesn't output json (toString is unlikely used for serialization). what you need is a converter for your request object to serialized json. common json libraries are jackson and gson (and many others).

Comment: I'll update it using javax json in a few if I run across another error. Thanks.